# Can't resolve "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement GCM push notifications on my android app and I'm following the guide here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client to the best of my understanding but I'm getting the error in Android Studio saying "can't resolve symbol: GcmReceiver"

I've literally just copy pasted what it says in the guide to my manifest and installed Google Play Services through the SDK Manager but it's still telling me it can't resolve it.

[image]

My understanding is that this a class that should be located in the classpath somewhere now that I've added the library considering all of the other classes like "MyGcmListenerService" have a custom package whereas it has a static one. Nowhere I've looked is helpful on this issue, can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My code (literally just copy pasted from the example):

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if you added the dependency to your app's level gradle script.

> dependencies { compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+" }

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi Jai, i'm new so i can't comment yet, but i believe that doing what i suggest could fix his issue, it parcially provide an answer. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have done that, although instead of downloading unnecessary packages I don't need I only added 'compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0"', to the dependencies as per https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup under "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable"

Comment: It turns out that by specifying 7.8.0 as opposed to 7.5.+ it wasn't finding the correct package. This fixed my problem. Thank you.